# Can't write in a .spp file remotely

Tags: c, linux, networking, network-programming

I don't know if somebody can help me with my problem, because I don't know if it is a *programming issue* or a *networking issue*. However, I will explain the whole suitation.
I am working on a mesh testbed, and I would like to run the *pacifier protocol* which is developed by someone for some reason.

The problem is that when I try to run the probing (which is a part of the configuration to run the pacifier) on the testbed nodes using the perl script `“run_probing.pl”`, the *.spp* file that contains the results didn’t created, but when I run the probing command manually on any two nodes *for example* using the command `./probing –a  10.1.1.26  -i  26`, I got that *.spp* files.
The command sent from perl script using pssh service. I check the process id using the command `ps aux`, and I found that the command

```
  $cmd ="/usr/bin/pssh -p 1 -t 120 -l amr -A -h temp_overlay.crap \"/map/more_pacifier/probing -a $allusnips[$sitecount] -i $allusnipids[$sitecount] > /dev/null 2>&1 &  \" ";
```

is executed in the background for both devices since the process id for that command is in the process id list which means that there is no problem with the pssh service itself. But still I don't get any .spp file in the `/map/more_pacifier` directory which is specified in the *probing.c* code.

For the probing.c code, since it is very long (around 400 lines), so I will put the part corresponding to writing in the .spp file:

```
FILE *fl;
 if(argc < 3) {
usage();
exit(-1);
}
while ((ch = getopt(argc, argv, "h:a:i:d:")) != -1)
 switch (ch) {
 case 'h':
   help();
   exit(0);
 case 'a':
   inaddr = inet_addr(optarg);  // IP Address
   memset((char*) &myip, 0x0, sizeof(myip));
   bcopy((char*) &inaddr, (char*) &myip, sizeof(inaddr));
   strcpy(myipstr, inet_ntoa(myip));
   fprintf(stderr, "My IP is %s, %s\n", inet_ntoa(myip), myipstr);
  break;
 case 'i':
  myipid = atoi(optarg);
  fprintf(stderr, "My ID is %d\n", myipid);
  break;
default:
  usage();
  exit(-1);
}

sprintf(lossfile, "/map/more_pacifier/%d.spp", myipid);
fl = fopen(lossfile, "w");

 for(i=0; i<NUMNODES; i++)
  ND.NHBR_Table[i].recvcount = 0;
 ND.numProbePktsSent = 0;
```

I don't know why I'm not getting the *.spp file* when running the command via `run_probing.pl` script.

Is it something with the permission access for this file? but I use `chmod 755` command to give the full access of the user.

I will really appreciate your help, It waste lots of time on this strange behavior without any result :(